# R: Updating my package for the upcoming ggplot2 version 2.3.0

Tags: r, ggplot2, devtools, bioconductor

I have previously created an R-package called `seqCAT` for variant analysis of high throughput sequencing data, which is available at [Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/seqCAT.html) (or [GitHub](https://github.com/fasterius/seqCAT) for the development version). I was just informed by an automatic mail from the guys working on the *tidyverse*, notifying my that my package [breaks](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md#ggplot2-2219000) with the planned changes for the `ggplot2` package (current devel `2.2.1.9000`, planned release `2.3.0`). I made the necessary changes in my local git repo, and my package now works with the new `ggplot2` version. However...

One of the required changes is not backwards compatible. Several of my previous tests used the data from `ggplot_build(<plot object>)$layout$panel_ranges`, in order to check that test plots were built correctly. The `panel_ranges` part has been changed to `panel_params` in the upcoming `ggplot2` version (which does make more sense).

While easily fixed, I'm now unsure how to deploy this change. The `seqCAT` package is my first (and only) package, and I've never had to do something like this before. I can't simply deploy the changes directly, as it breaks under the currently released `ggplot2` version. Do I just wait until June 25th (when the next `ggplot` is scheduled to release) and deploy it then? What about the overlapping time from `ggplot2`'s release and `seqCAT`'s build? How should I deal with future compatibility, *i.e.* should I add some maximum allowed `ggplot2` version to my current release branch?

I have a fairly small number of users, at least by the download statistics, but I'd prefer to make the transition as simple as possible for them. I don't really know how to approach these kind of things, given my non-CS background in biology/biotech. Any tips on how to think around this and how to solve it? Maybe I'm just overthinking it?

Comment: You can explicit require a certain version of a package so you can require the newer version of ggplot2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267140/possible-to-state-explicit-versions-of-package-dependencies. Or you can just change your code to check for either `panel_ranges` or `panel_params` and just use which ever is present.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point, to check for which one is present and use that! Didn't think of that. I think I'll implement it in that way, and just update the package straight away. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to get back to this thread and say that I did indeed implement a version check and use either `panel_ranges` or `panel_params` as appropriate. If you want to create an answer with that I'd be happy to accept the answer, @MrFlick!